# Rescale line thickness in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

When I change the size argument in geom_line for ggplot2 it rescales the entire graph and makes my lines thick again.

```r
ggplot() + 
 geom_line(data=dT_data, aes(x=Wavelength,y=TIME_0,color='black',size=1.0)) +
  geom_point(color = 'black',size = 0.5) +
 geom_line(data=dT_data, aes(x=Wavelength,y=TIME_30,color='blue',size=1.0)) + 
  geom_point(color = 'blue',size = 0.5) +
 geom_line(data=dT_data, aes(x=Wavelength,y=TIME_60,color='red',size=1.0)) + 
  geom_point(color = 'red',size = 0.5) +
 ylab(label="Absorbance") + xlab("Wavelength")
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to specify `size` directly in a `geom_`, place it outside the `aes()` call.

Comment: first of all that's bad practice to have multiple geoms. Convert your data to long format: ```library(reshape2);
long_dT <- melt(dT_data, id.vars = "Wavelength");
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=long_dT, aes(x=Wavelength,y=value,color=variable,size=1.0)) +
  geom_point(color = variable,size = 0.5) +
  ylab(label="Absorbance") + xlab("Wavelength")
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys, Jon Spring's fix worked but I'll give yours a try M-M because you're right, I can see how this would be a nightmare with more lines.